"Dual action" $G \curvearrowright \mathbb{C}[X]$ on the coordinate ring of affine variety
Let $G$ be a group which acts on an affine variety $X$. Then we get an induced action on the coordinate ring of $X$, $G \curvearrowright \mathbb{C}[X]$. These set of notes refer to this action on the coordinate ring as a "dual action". Is "dual" used a technical sense here?
Some thoughts so far:
For $X = \mathbb{A}^n$, we have that $\mathbb{C}[X] = \text{Sym}^\bullet X^\vee$, where $X^\vee$ is the dual vector space of $X$ spanned by the coordinate functions $x_i : X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. The "obvious" induced action on this is $(g \cdot f)(p) = f(g \cdot p)$ for $f \in \mathbb{C}[X]$, $g \in G$, $p \in X$, which we correct by a sign to get the desired (left) action. In some sense this justifies the use of "dual", since we have used a "dual" vector space.
For a general affine variety $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$, we have $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{A}^n] \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{C}[X]$. In particular, $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is still generated by $x_i : X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, and thus the action of $G$ on the $x_i$'s from above gives an action on the whole coordinate ring $\mathbb{C}[X]$.
However, this doesn't feel very satisfying - the notion of the dual vector space doesn't feel critical to the construction, and it all seems to hang on this connection $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{A}^n] = \text{Sym}^\bullet (\mathbb{A}^n)^\vee$, which doesn't seem to be relevant anywhere else in algebraic geometry (that I have seen). Is there a deeper way to understand "dual action" or does the name indeed come from this idea?

"Dual" here just means that the functor $X \mapsto \mathbb{C}[X]$ is contravariant.

That sort of makes sense. I guess this answers the question. Thank you
